# Android java method - Can a parameter be more than one type?

Tags: java, android, methods

I'm new to java/android and would really appreciate help with this. I would like my java method to be able to take in more than one type for the parameter. For example the variable myButton could be an ImageButton or just a Button. The code inside myFunction is valid for whether myButton is an ImageButton or a Button.

```
if (condition) {
    ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButtonID);
    myFunction(myButton);
} else {
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonID);
    myFunction(myButton);
}

public void myFunction(Button or ImageButton myButton) {
    ....identical code for myButton which could be an ImageButton or Button....
}
```

I could obviously write out 2 funcions for parameter type and call it when applicable but that seems like a waste and there must be a quicker way. How can I do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Java's classic method Overloading would be of help.

Comment: Generics? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html. and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131410/implementing-methods-from-an-interface-but-with-different-parameters

Comment: How would I apply generics for my simple case?

Comment: Sounds like inheritance is the solution here. Declare the function parameter as a common supertype.

Answer (score 5):

If both classes have a common interface that can be used inside your method, you can use it and catch both types.

Otherwise, you can use [overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) or [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) method.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what the method does to the passed in parameter.

Usually, you'd use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). Looking at the inheritance graphs,

```
ImageButton extends ImageView extends View extends Object
```

and

```
Button extends TextView extends View extends Object
```

The most specific common superclass is `View`. If the method can work on `View`s, then you should specify the parameter type to be a `View`:

```
public void myFunction(View view) {
    //...
}
```

If the method does different things to `ImageButton`s  and `Button`s, then you can use [method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading). That is, two methods that have take different parameters:

```
public void myFunction(ImageButton imageButton) {
    //...
}

public void myFunction(Button button) {
    //...
}
```

In rare cases, a [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)-based solution could also work. Note that the compiler will actually generate copies of the code for each different type passed in, so you should prefer polymorphism-based solution when you can:

```
public <ParamType extends View> void myFunction(ParamType param) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use common super class of the Button and ImageButton which is for example View and then:

```
public void myFunction(View view) {
    if(view instanceof Button) {
        Button btn = (Button) view;
        // do something with Button instance
    }

    if(view instanceof ImageButton) {
        ImageButton iBtn = (ImageButton) view;
        // do something with Image Button instance
    }
}
```

Comment: Needing to resort to reflection (`instanceof`) is usually a code smell indicative of design problems.

Comment: The same thing is being done to Button and ImageButton...so the same code would be repeated twice which is kinda inefficient

Comment: I agree with laalto about reflection. It will be easier to find optimal solution with source code provided.